# How to receive data from webhook which is created in third party app?

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks

There is website which send user data when new user is registered on it by web hook. I have created webhook on that website now i dont know how to receive data on my website ?

[image]

How I can acieve this by using php ?

Comment: An external site can never access your `localhost`. You need to have laravel running on live server, and just create a route. The external sites makes a call to your server, similar to how a user makes a call to your server

Comment: I am using laravel when server will post data to this url.I will get this data in my controller?

Comment: Yes, just like a user would submit form data to your site. No difference. Define a route, handle it in your controller, access the data on the `request` object

Comment: So there is no way to test it? without putting on live server?

Comment: Sure, you can simply add a unit test to the route, sending the data you'd expect from the remote server. You can just assume that server sends correct data.

Comment: Also, you need to create an exception for the route you create in the VerifyCsrfToken.php else it won't allow it. Read this (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) to have a better understanding. Cheers!

Comment: Can i do this by ngrok?

Comment: You can use expose to create a tunnel to your local development, as you would with ngrok but waaay simpler  https://beyondco.de/docs/expose/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following method. I use ngrok for this purpose which gives me url . I added url in Webhook of third party app. Now I am receiving data when any user is created on that third party webiste